# Cocoa: Sliding a HUD window from a dock icon

Tags: cocoa, macos

I want to accomplish a specific animated start-up behaviour for a utility application window. When the application starts I want the application window (a HUD window) to slide out from the dock, comparable to the way a drawer slides out of a window. I would appreciate any hints on how to accomplish this, if it is at all possible.